# Using WP meta query to show custom post types by a start and finish date

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called *Events*, and a page that displays events for one month. Each event has 2 custom fields `start_date` and `finish_date`, which store the date as `yymmdd`.

If an event spans over two different months it is only appearing in the month of the start date. I'm stuck on how to show it in the month of the finish date as well. For example, if I have an event with a start date of 19/03/2014 and a finish date of 19/04/2013 it should appear in both the month of March and April.

I am using this code:

```
// Get chosen month to display from URL
$events_month = sanitize_text_field($_GET["month"]);
$events_year = sanitize_text_field($_GET["year"]);

// Convert chosen month to display to a timestamp
$ts = strtotime("$events_month $events_year");

// Create chosen month start end end dates to use for query
$month_start_date = date('Ym01', $ts);
$month_end_date = date('Ymt', $ts);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => array($month_start_date, $month_end_date),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
);

$events = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: What format is the start_date saved in, if it's not Ymt you could have problems? This seems a roundabout way of doing things anyway, why not just store the event date as a unix time?

Comment: It's a date field in advanced custom fields, it saves it in the format: yymmdd The issue is how can I display the events in a month which is past the start date month (i.e. the event ends in the next month)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need an `OR` in your `meta_query` to check if the `start_date` is in the selected month ***or*** the `end_date` is in the selected month...

Try something like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(

    'relation' => 'OR',

    array(
        'key'     => 'start_date',
        'value'   => array( $month_start_date, $month_end_date ),
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ),

    array(
        'key'     => 'finish_date',
        'value'   => array( $month_start_date, $month_end_date ),
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ),
)
```

Check WP Codex for further details: [/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)